# Extjs 4.1 Check Change Listener

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

What is the right way to handle menu check items  events ?

I have this menu:

```
 {
      xtype: 'button',
      id: 'types_btn',
      autoWidth: true,
      text: 'Types',
      menu: {
              xtype: 'menu',
              frame: true,
              id: 'types_menue',

              items: [
                       {
                         xtype: 'menucheckitem',
                         id: 'f_type',
                         text: 'first',
                         listeners: {
                            checkchange: {
                                    fn: me.onFirstButtoncheckchange,
                                    scope: me
                                    }
                                      }
                       },
                       {
                        xtype: 'menucheckitem',
                        id: 's_type',
                    text: 'second',
                         listeners: {
                            checkchange: {
                                    fn: me.onSecondButtoncheckchange,
                                    scope: me
                                    }
                                      }
                       }
```

Then the functions:

```
onFirstButtoncheckchange: function(menucheckitem, checked, options) {

    var t = Ext.getCmp('f_type');
               if (t.checked)
                   goToFunction(???);
                 .
                 .
    },
 onSecondButtoncheckchange: function(menucheckitem, checked, options) {

    var t = Ext.getCmp('s_type');
               if (t.checked)
                   goToFunction(???);
                 .
                 .
    },
```

1- Is there anyway to use one listener and gather all different functions in it ?

2- How can I send the current item to goToFunction() as you see in the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make an handler for each menu check item:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'menucheckitem',
    text: 'select all' ,
    id: 'first' ,
    listeners: {
        checkchange: me.myHandler
    }
},{
    xtype: 'menucheckitem',
    text: 'select specific' ,
    id: 'second' ,
    listeners: {
        checkchange: me.myHandler
    }
}]
```

And your handler defined as follows:

```
myHandler: function (menucheckitem, checked, opts) {
    switch (menucheckitem.getId ()) {
        // Here handles the first
        case 'first':
            if (checked) {
                console.log ('First checked!');
                goToFunction ();
            }
            break;
        // Here handles the second
        case 'second':
            if (checked) {
                console.log ('Second checked!');
                goToFunction ();
            }
            break;
        default:
            console.log ('Whatever!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the listener doesn't get triggered quite often. You can use checkHandler config instead.